# Read content of the uploading files without using FileReference.load() method in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I'm going to implement a file uploading application using flex 3.5 and php. In the flex code I need to read the content of the uploaded file without calling the FileReference.load() method (Since it is a big issue when uploading large files). I checked many online articles and didn't find a way to do this in flex. 
Can anyone tell me if there is anyway to access the content of this file without using FileReference.load() method?

because I need to chunk the data after that.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to upload file with size larger than what FileReference can handle, my suggestion is to leverage file uploading functionality with php or other server side file upload script.

Once your data is available to server, get bytearray of file contents and send to your flex app.

Of course, this is indirect way, but is only solution I can think of, unless you can split file and upload in batch!